# Why do I get, "ElementAtOrDefault' is not a member of 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection"?

Tags: vb.net, sln-file

I am trying to get a VB solution to run (just took it over to maintain). When I try to run it via F5, I get several errors, the first of which is:

```
Error   13  'ElementAtOrDefault' is not a member of 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow)'.  C:\MemberOrderEntry\MembersOrderEntry\MembersOrderEntry\App_Code\commonClass.vb 908 16  MembersOrderEntry
```

But 2-clicking it in the Error List pane takes me to this line (line 908):

```
Return dset.Tables(0)(0)("Result")
```

The string "*ElementAtOrDefault*" appears nowhere in the code. How does the line above wreak this havoc?

BTW, some of ther other err msgs seem very odd, such as "*'String' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level*" and "*Type 'Exception' is not defined*"

It seems something fundamental is flawed in this code or its configuration. The Project's Bin folder contains DAL05.dll (and DAL05.pdb), as well as four Telerik DLLs.

Comment: `dset.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Result")`  Rows is not a default property like `Items` often is

Comment: Cool; I wonder why that code ever worked (I assume it did, as this is a legacy project)...